# PyInstaller executable which uses wxPython missing Python Framework build

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller to build native executables for my Python program.

I run the cli and generate my executable using the command : `pyinstaller app.py`

When I go to run my executable I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py:623: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Arabic
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Devanagari
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Mono
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Sans
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Sans-Condensed
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Sans-Hebrew
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Sans-Thai-Looped
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Serif
Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts/IBM-Plex-Thai
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac.
```

I am using the wxPython library to render a GUI for my program - and I believe this message relates to that.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: There is an example of using PyInstaller with a wxPython application in the wxPython source tree, at https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/samples/doodle/superdoodle.spec. I don't recall needing to do anything special there to make it work, but you can probably use it to help figure out where the problem is located. If building superdoodle.app doesn't work then look at your Python and PyInstaller installs, because it does still work for me. If it does work, then look closer at your application and how you are using PyInstaller with it.

Comment: @RobinDunn this is a problem with the OPs operating system not wx or PyInstaller.